# Linux shell CSV viewer tool that can freeze the header?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, csv

It's now hard to write one without the capability of freezing the header, like

```
function viewcsv() {
   cat $1 | sed -e "s/,,/, ,/g" | column -s, -t | less -#2 -N -S
}
```

But is there a utility that allows me to freeze the header, or change the one above to allow it?

[EDIT:] by freezing the header I mean when I scroll up and down with "less", the first line remains there on the top of the screen. Those are usually the header information I want to see even when scrolling down thousands of lines, such as "Date", "Symbol", etc.

Comment: with "utility" you mean some kind of editor? Note that asking for tools is a bit off-topic (and the script looks usable enough).

Comment: @fedorqui not an editor, just a viewer

Comment: OK. I am sure some `vi` expert can write some fancy script for this.

Comment: OpenOffice is overkill, but will do this.

Comment: See http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/148781/96718

Comment: heyy, did you find a way to have headers freezed while reading in `less` ? I also use the same command but need headers to be freezed somehow

Answer (score 4):

I adapted this [How to scroll large datafile while keeping header](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/60512/43764) to your wishes:

```
vim -R -u NONE -N +'map <right> 2zl
                    map <left> 2zh
                    map q :qa<CR>
                    se nu sbo=hor scb nowrap
                    1sp
                    winc w
                   ' <(sed -e "s/,,/, ,/g" $1|column -ts,)
```

- `-R` Readonly mode.
- `-u NONE` all
      initializations from files and environment variables are
      skipped (they could interfere with the working of e. g. `winc w`)
- `-N` Not compatible mode (otherwise key names like `<right>` might not work)
- `map <right> 2zl` to make <kbd>→</kbd> scroll horizontally like `less -#2`
- `map <left> 2zh` to make <kbd>←</kbd> scroll horizontally like `less -#2`
- `map q :qa<CR>` to make <kbd>Q</kbd> quit like `less`
- `se nu sbo=hor scb nowrap` set options:

  - 'number' - Print the line number in front of each line.
  - 'scrollopt'=hor - Bind horizontal scrolling for 'scrollbind' windows
  - 'scrollbind' - to scroll the header line together with the rest of the data
  - 'nowrap' - lines will not wrap
    and only part of long lines will be displayed.
- `1sp` Split current window in two (new window has 1 line, the header)
- `winc w` move cursor to body window

Answer (score 0):

Are you just asking about not changing the first line?  (It's not at all clear to me what you mean by 'freezing', but 'not modifying' seems like a reasonable interpretation.)

```
viewcsv() {
  sed -e "1!s/,,/, ,/g" "$1" | column -s, -t | less -#2 -N -S
}
```

(Removed the redundant keyword 'function' and the UUOC.  The relevant addition is the address scope `1!` in `sed`.)

Or perhaps you mean that you want the first line to not go through `column`:

```
viewcsv() {
  { sed 1q "$1"; sed -e 1d -e 's/,,/, ,/g' "$1" |
     column -s, -t; } | less -#2 -N -S
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I edited my original post. By freezing the header I mean when I scroll up and down with "less", the first line remains there on the top of the screen. Those are usually the header information I want to see even when scrolling down thousands of lines, such as "Date", "Symbol", etc.

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head, you could tailor the `less` prompt to display the CSV headers instead of the usual prompt.

```
viewcsv () {
    less -PM"$(sed -n 's/,/ /gp;q' "$1")" -M -N -S "$1"
}
```

(You can still see where you are in the file with `=` -- I suppose you could replace the short or medium prompt just as well.)

If your data contains percent signs or question marks, they will need to be escaped, as these have a special meaning in the `less` prompt definition.  See the description of the `-P` option and the section PROMPTS in the `less` manual for details.

Maybe you could even throw in some terminal escape sequences to get the prompt (or part of it) displayed at the top of the screen, but the trivial solution would superimpose the prompt over data you want to see.

Comment: As an aside, CSV files with headers are a pest.  Data should remain data.

Comment: I tried it and got this error when running the viewcsv function: ``sed: -e expression #1, char 2: unknown command: `/'``

Comment: @DanielSerodio I seem to have left in a spurious slash; try now. Thanks for the ping.

Comment: Thanks, now it doesn't give any errors but the `less` prompt is empty. I tried unsetting my custom `LESS` var. inside the `viewcsv` but the prompt is still empty.

Comment: It worked for me but maybe your CSV is different than I assume; does the `sed` script print what you expect in isolation?